# Dominion rule clarification: Repeater actions + choice actions

Tags: dominion

When using a "repeating" action, such as Throne room, with a "choice" action, such as Pawn or Nobles, can you make a different choice on each repeated action?

For example, Throne Room states:

> Choose an action from your hand, play it twice.

Nobles states:

> Choose one: +3 cards, +2 actions

After playing these two cards, can you make the choice to get +3 cards from the first play of Nobles, and +2 actions from the second play of Nobles triggered by Throne Room?

Also, if you may choose each time, what order are these actions resolved? Would I gain 3 cards, then the second Nobles choice is made, or are both Nobles actions simultaneous, so both choices have to be made before the first can be resolved?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I read this as follows:

"Play it twice" applied to `Pawn` means:

- Play `Pawn` and then
- Play `Pawn` again

I.e. there are two subsequent plays of pawn, which implies

1. You can make different choices during each play
2. Benefits you gain during the first play are available during the second play

Answer (score 7):

As far as choice and action resolution goes, it's as though you have two of the card, and play them one after the other. Using Noble as the example in this case, one could choose to draw three cards during the first play, then, based on the cards you draw you could decide whether you want the +2 actions or three more cards. Nobles is my favorite card to stack with Throne Room, by far.

As another example, let's say you play a Golem on top of a Throne Room. You would draw through your deck until you get two action cards, then determine the order in which you want to play them, then resolve all their actions (if one of them were a Throne Room, you would also resolve the actions of the card you stack on it twice), then draw through your deck until you get two more action cards, then determine the order in which you want to play them, then resolve their actions, one after the other.

Also, it's important to note that what I'm saying here is really just an expanded version of S.P.Floyd - seanizer's answer, which was here before mine.